# If $\sin a+\sin b=2$, then show that $\sin(a+b)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin a+\sin b=2$, then show that $\sin(a+b)=0$.

I have tried to solve this problem in the following way :

\begin{align}&\sin a + \sin b=2 \\
\Rightarrow &2\sin\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)=2\\
\Rightarrow &\sin\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)=1
\end{align}

What will be the next ?

Comment: What does \Ra mean?

Comment: Sorry, for this mistake. A correction has  done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT:

As $-1\le \sin x\le 1$ for real $x$

$\implies -2\le \sin a+\sin b\le 2$

The equality occurs if $\sin a=\sin b=1$

$a=2n\pi+\frac\pi2,  b=2m\pi+\frac\pi2,$ for some integer $m,n$

So, $a+b=2\pi(m+n)+\pi=\pi(2m+2n+1)$ and we know $\sin r\pi=0$ for integer $r$

---

Alternatively, if $\sin x=1,\cos x=\pm\sqrt{1-1^2}=0\implies $ here $\cos a=\cos b=0$

and we know $\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a \sin b$

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value of the $sin$ function is 1, at $\pi / 2 + 2k\pi$, for any integer $k$.

So $a = \pi / 2 + 2k\pi$, and $b = \pi / 2 + 2l\pi$, for any integers $k$, $l$.

Therefore, $\sin(a + b) = \sin(\pi + 2(k + l)\pi) = 0$.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ could also be $5\pi/2$, or $9\pi/2$, or $13\pi/2$, or...

Comment: Since no ranges for $a$ and $b$ were specified, you may need to say that in general $a=\pi/2 + k2\pi$, $b=\pi/2+\ell 2 \pi$, with $k,l$ whole numbers. Then $a+b = \pi+ (k+l)2\pi = (2m+1)\pi$.

Comment: @ChrisEagle, Lucozade Good points.  I've edited my answer to include $+ 2k\pi$.

Comment: @rgettman, $a,b$ may not be equal:)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Corrected again.

Comment: @rgettman, thanks, $+1$